# Rails - session lost after returning from a submit (POST)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session

I am integrating the Liberty Reserve shopping cart into my Rails application. Calling LR (with the fork submit) works perfectly and LR also redirects back to my page after the successful postings. But my session is lost when the app returns.

The page looks as follows:

```
<form action="https://sci.libertyreserve.com/en" method="GET">
<input type="hidden" name="lr_acc" value="XXXXX">
<input type="hidden" name="lr_store" value="XXX">
<input type="hidden" name="lr_merchant_ref" value="1">
<input type="submit" value="Liberty Reserve"/>
</form>
```

The way LR works, is after the user has successfully booked his transaction, LR redirects back to my webpage but my authentication fails because the session variables are all gone.

I believe it has something to do with the CSRF-TOKEN that the rails application requires but LR obviously is not providing.

Can I deactivate the CSRF feture for one specific page/action or is there any other workaround?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I am starting to Rails as a Facebook Application and going trough the Koala Lib. I read somewhere to turn off the feature "protect from fogery"

For a test you simply comment out protect_from_forgery in your ApplicationController, but just to see if that works for you.
    class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
      #protect_from_forgery

If that works you could try to make an exception for your specific controller/actionHere.
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/RequestForgeryProtection/ClassMethods.html

Be careful. It might be one Vulnerability more to deal with.
http://ruby.about.com/od/security/a/forgeryprotect.htm

Comment: After reading through some more of the information, the "trick" is to make sure the "external" application returns to my web page with a GET and not with a POST, the protect from forgery is a feature only applicable to POSTs.

Comment: I've completely overseen, that your were using GET. Good that you have found a solution.

Answer (score 2):

Did you use form tag ?

```
<%= form_tag do %>
  Form contents
<% end %>
```

other view

```
<%= form_tag(c_add_path, method: 'post', enctype: 'multipart/form-data', style: 'text-align: left;') do %>
  Form contents
<% end %>
```

This tag generate html with session key, so you can use POST without losing session

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html

Comment: Despite not addressing the OP question (OP is not in control of code rendering a form for this POST request), this solved the problem for me.  I was losing session contents during a login challenge.  My new session form was built with regular HTML, which meant it did not include the hidden input with name "authenticity_token".  The lack of authenticity token in the POST was resetting my session.  Changing to using `form_tag` added the missing hidden input and solved my problem.  Thanks @Andrew